# CheckBox On GridView Lose State after selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I Have a Problem With GridView CheckBoxes.
    I added Selection For My GridView and Every time i Select a Row, After PostBack My Checked CheckBoxes Loss their value. any Advice ?

Added Page Load.

```
My GirdView:
----------------
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="RulesGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="8" DataSourceID="RulesDataSource" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCreated="RulesGridView_RowCreated" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RulesGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

C# Code behind:
-------------------
  protected void RulesGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] =           "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
                e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.RulesGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            }
        }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            Session["RuleList"] = new List<Rule>();
            Session.Timeout = 180;
            //LstRules.Items.Clear();
            string folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MovieCreatorGUIRulesFolder"];
            XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Rule>));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(folder + "\\DB" + txtdbnum.Text + "Rules.xml");
            List<Rule> RuleList = (List<Rule>)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            Session["RuleList"] = RuleList;
        }
        ZoomInCommon.Users.UserInfo userInfo = PublishManager.GetCurrentYoutubeUser(-1);
        if (userInfo == null)
            txtYoutubeLoginUser.Text = "Not Logged In";
        else
            txtYoutubeLoginUser.Text = userInfo.DisplayName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code that initializes the text boxes. It sounds to me like it just re-initializes the controls when you post back.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //code that loads or builds your checkboxes
}
```

Comment: Well the whole point is that you don't load the previous state of the checkbox control. You leave it alone on a postback.

Comment: e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.RulesGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);                                           I guess that this line couses the postback but i cant wrap it with if (!Page.IsPostBack) because the selection wont work

Comment: Yes, that would cause a postback - but that's not where you need to handle it. Can you provide the code that is the Page_Load or Page_Init method?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the PostBack:

```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" 
                  runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
                  OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are data binding your gridview on every request then you need to save the state of the checkboxes somewhere and re-instate their previous state soon after databinding

#### Update

See the minimalistic example below

HTML

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<br /><br />

<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="PostBack" OnClick="btn_Click" />

<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="FirstName">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="dataKey" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Page code-behind

```
    IList<Person> _allPersons;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _allPersons = Helper.GetPersons();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gv.DataSource = _allPersons;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedPersons = GetSelectedPersons();
        lblOutput.Text = string.Join(",", selectedPersons.Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName)));
    }

    private IList<Person> GetSelectedPersons()
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            var chkSelect = row.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
            var dataKey = row.FindControl("dataKey") as HiddenField;

            if (chkSelect != null && dataKey != null && chkSelect.Checked)
            {
                var person = _allPersons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstName == dataKey.Value);

                if (person != null)
                    persons.Add(person);
            }
        }

        return persons;
    }
```

And finally, if you are curious, the implementation details of Person and the data Helper

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Helper
{
    public static IList<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        return new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){FirstName = "Kanye", LastName ="West", Age = 33},
            new Person(){FirstName = "Justin", LastName ="Timberlake", Age = 18},
            new Person(){FirstName = "Celine", LastName ="Dion", Age = 38},
            new Person(){FirstName = "Samantha", LastName ="Jade", Age = 33},
            new Person(){FirstName = "Marshal", LastName ="Matters", Age = 35},
            new Person(){FirstName = "Armando", LastName ="Perez", Age = 14}
        };
    }
}
```

Hope it makes sense

Leo

Comment: Sounds good but how do i get the checkboxes data and re-instate it ?

Comment: There's so many ways you can achieve that. Off the top of my head without looking how you've got thingsimplemented.  You can postback when a sselection occurs, save the value and any other processing. You can also use the command event. You can also use javascript to save the values to a hidden field, etc.

Comment: If you want an example i could code something for you but it'll have to wait until tomorrow